# Calendar Arbitrage in a Vol Surface

Tags: implied-volatility, arbitrage

I am trying to determine the condition such that my implied vol surface doesn't have calendar arbitrage. I have done research and found that one such condition is that total variance should increase along the time axis. However, I want to find a different condition using the call option price or forwards, or something to that extent.

Furthermore, I do not want to assume proportional dividends, same forward moneyness, etc. The information I do know is option price and forward prices.

My approach is something as follows. Let X and Y be unknowns. at t=0, I would need to pay (or receive) $XC(t_1)+YC(t_2)$ where $C(T)=\exp(-rT)BS(F_T,K,T,r,\sigma)$. Note that I am assuming that we are working with the same strike $K$. Let $X=1$ for simplicty. At $t=1$, if $S_{t_1}<K$, then my call expiring at $t_1$ would be worth nothing, and closing out the portfolio position, the payoff would be $-Y\exp(rT_1)C(t_2)$. If $S_{t_1}>K$, then my payoff would be $S_{t_1}-K-Y\exp(rT_1)C(t_2)$.

I'm not sure how I would continue my argument from here, though perhaps I want to use the fact that $C(t) \ge \exp(-rt)(F_t-K)$. I know I would first need to find out the quantity of $Y$ first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Jim

Comment: I'm missing something. Where you say `-Y*exp(r*T1)*C(t2)`, do you mean `BS` where you say `C`? If not, I don't see why a call's price would always change by the risk-free interest rate (even if the underlying remained at the same price, there would be theta decay). I know you're assuming the same strike price, but if the underlying price drops, wouldn't `C(t2)` be considerably lower?

Answer (score 9):

In a *pure diffusion* setting, you can equivalently write no calendar arbitrage constraints:

- In terms of *implied volatility*: total implied variance should be non decreasing in time, and that, *for any given forward moneyness level*, see [Gatheral](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646&ved=0ahUKEwiS0ImU7sDLAhXL1xoKHce2Az8QFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNHfk0i_J9jZI7Mj_5aaQoaHHcQvvA&sig2=6aI0AmRxtCam0-8_V81sxg) top of page 4.
- In terms of *European option prices*: see [Gatheral](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646&ved=0ahUKEwiS0ImU7sDLAhXL1xoKHce2Az8QFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNHfk0i_J9jZI7Mj_5aaQoaHHcQvvA&sig2=6aI0AmRxtCam0-8_V81sxg) end of page 3.

The price-based constraint builds on the following lemma

> **[Lemma]** *If $X_t$ is a martingale, $L < \infty$ a real constant and $0 < t_1 < t_2$ two future times, then 
>   $$E[(X_{t_2}-L)^+] \geq E [(X_{t_1}-L)^+] $$*
>
> **[Proof]** 
>   \begin{align}
> E[(X_{t_2}-L)^+ \vert \mathcal {F}_0 ] &= E[\ E [(X_{t_2}-L)^+ \ \vert \mathcal {F}_1 \ ]\  \vert \mathcal {F}_0 ] \\
> &\geq E[\ \left( E[X_{t_2}-L \ \vert \mathcal {F}_1 \ ] \right)^+ \ \vert \mathcal {F}_0 ] \\
> &\geq E[ (X_{t_1}-L)^+ \ \vert \mathcal {F}_0 ]
> \end{align} 
>   where we have used, in respective order:
>
> - Tower property of conditional expectation
> - Jensen's inequality ($f : x \rightarrow x^+$ is a convex function)
> - The fact that $X_t$ is a martingale

In a more general setting, one can still **use this lemma to derive price-based constraints**. The only question is: what martingale $X_t$ should we consider?

**[Proportional dividends]**

In a pure diffusion setting, it made sense to use $X_t = S_t/F (0,t) $, because $dS_t/S_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dW_t \Rightarrow S_t = F(0,t)X_t$, where $X_t=\mathcal{E}(\int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s)$ is indeed a martingale (Doléans-Dade exponential). Applying the lemma then gives:

\begin{align*}
& E[(X_{t_2}-L)^+] \geq E [(X_{t_1}-L)^+] \\
\iff & E\left[\left(\frac{S_{t_2}}{F(0,t_2)}-L\right)^+\right] \geq E \left[\left(\frac{S_{t_1}}{F(0,t_1)}-L\right)^+\right] \\
\iff & \frac{1}{F(0,t_2)} E[(S_{t_2}-LF(0,t_2))^+] \geq \frac{1}{F(0,t_1)} E[(S_{t_1}-LF(0,t_1))^+] \\
\iff & \frac{\tilde{C}(K_2,t_2)}{F(0,t_2)} \geq \frac{\tilde{C}(K_1,t_1)}{F(0,t_1)} 
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{C}(K,T)$ denotes an *undiscounted* call price and $K_1=LF(0,t_1)$, $K_2=LF(0,t_2)$. This is precisely Gatheral's result:
$$ \frac{C_2}{K_2} \geq \frac{C_1}{K_1} $$
(in his paper, he always uses *undiscounted* call prices and he chose $L=e^k$), since
$$ \frac{K_2}{K_1} = \frac{F(0,t_2)}{F(0,t_1)} $$

**[Cash & Proportional dividends]**

In a more elaborate setting, it will depend on how you model dividends. [Buehler](http://ssrn.com/abstract=1141877) for instance suggests a no-arbitrage pricing framework which can accommodate cash dividends, proportional dividends, and/or any mix of the two. In his model, it makes sense to use the martingale $X_t = (S_t-D_t)/(F (0,t) - D_t) $ where $D_t $ is related to the future dividend stream (all divs are assumed to be known in advance). Applying the lemma gives:

\begin{align*}
& E[(X_{t_2}-L)^+] \geq E [(X_{t_1}-L)^+] \\
\iff & E\left[\left(\frac{S_{t_2}-D_{t_2}}{F(0,t_2)-D_{t_2}}-L\right)^+\right] \geq E \left[\left(\frac{S_{t_1}-D_{t_1}}{F(0,t_1)-D_{t_1}}-L\right)^+\right] \\
\iff & \frac{E[(S_{t_2}-(D_{t_2}+L(F(0,t_2)-D_{t_2})))^+] }{F(0,t_2)-D_{t_2}} \geq \frac{E[(S_{t_1}-(D_{t_1}+L(F(0,t_1)-D_{t_1})))^+]}{F(0,t_1)-D_{t_1}} \\
\iff & \frac{\tilde{C}(K_2,t_2)}{F(0,t_2)-D_{t_2}} \geq \frac{\tilde{C}(K_1,t_1)}{F(0,t_1)-D_{t_1}}
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{C}(K,T)$ denotes an *undiscounted* call price and $K_1=D_{t_1}+L(F(0,t_1)-D_{t_1}))$, $K_2=D_{t_2}+L(F(0,t_2)-D_{t_2}))$.

Observe that when $(D_t)_{t\geq0} = 0$, we fall-back on Gatheral's result. In [Buehler](http://ssrn.com/abstract=1141877), $(D_t)_{t\geq0} = 0$ iff there are *no cash dividends* (meaning there could be either proportional dividends or no dividends at all). This is completely consistent with what we have said in the pure diffusion case.

**[Arbitrage opportunity]**

Finally, note that the above inequalities describe the calendar arbitrage opportunities. In the second situation for instance, a PF where you are long $\tilde{C}(K=K_2,T=t_2)$ and short $(F(0,t_2)-D_{t_2})/(F(0,t_1)-D_{t_1}) $ units of $\tilde{C}(K=K_1,T=t_1)$ should always have a positive value (we just showed that). If not, it is an arbitrage opportunity.

Comment: If you don't assume proportional dividends then there is only one way to specify the dynamics of 'the stock' properly, see H. Buehler's work. Anyway, I guess you'll start from the result I described above to find what you need, you just need to find the right martingale now!

Comment: I perfectly understand Gatheral's result. My main thing is to create an arbitrage portfolio instead, assuming forward prices that are not based on proportional dividends.

Comment: Ok. All I am saying is that you can use the same result to obtain a calendar arbitrage inequality, even with non prop dividends. For instance if you use the modelling assumptions described in \url{http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1141877}, you see that $X_t = (S_t - D_t)/(F_t - D_t)$ is a martingale with $F_t $ the forward price and $D_t$ can be computed from the expected div stream.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to applying the classic no arbitrage relationships in a *cleansed* domain where you have got rid of the effect of future (deterministic) div payments. Maybe chap 4 (esp. Section 4.3.1.) of this thesis will help you understand what I mean? \url {https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://repository.tudelft.nl/assets/uuid:3d888331-9f15-4ac2-9cfd-63d0b281cab8/Thesis_Merel_Stout.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj96Z7yx8LLAhUFIQ8KHfbfAsoQFggdMAA&usg=AFQjCNH0Rw9saM578IuGFgavKLQoMefkxw&sig2=i44ArcHUbDhjxCgOAEjNjw}

Comment: Quantuple, seems like a very interesting solution. In the gatheral paper, the European option price condition is that $\frac{C_2}{K_2}>\frac{C_1}{K_1}$. How would this change if you were using the different martingale $X_t=(S_t-D_t)/(F_t-D_t)$

Comment: Quantuple, what do you think of Devize's question?

Comment: I've edited my post to better show you what I mean, I hope I didn't make any mistakes, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: @Quantuple What for conclusion can we derived on the time dynamic implied variance surface $\frac{d}{dt} \omega(k, t)$ for discrete dividend? Obviously the black scholes doesn't apply anymore in this case, which makes the argument in Gatheral paper invalid